Shaving or cutting hair if performing HAJJ-E-TAMATTU’
Usually when we keep neeyath to offer qurban as men we don't shave or cut our hair from the 1st of dul haj till the qurban is offered, does the same apply when  we perform haj ? The confusion was as we will go for umra 1st and we need to trim the hair after we completed the umrah then after few days we prepare for haj
